# Incorrect conversion between pandas period and pandas timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

If I have the period `a`:

```
a = pd.Period('2405-10-01 00:00', 'H')
```

and I try and convert to a timestamp

```
a.to_timestamp()
```

why am I getting an incorrect conversion?

```
Timestamp('1821-03-13 00:25:26.290448384')
```

I am using:

```
pd.__version__
u'0.24.2'
```

Comment: Might depend on your pandas version - I get `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2405-10-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Either way, I'd guess that you're hitting some sort of overflow there.

Comment: From your edit, that is a fairly old version of pandas at this point. Might be worth updating if you're able.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I am using old python libraries for this project because I am migrating from really old python libraries.  I am working updating old `scikits.timeseries` objects to pandas and am needing to use `pd.Period`s.  They are foreign to me.

Comment: see [pd.Timestamp.max](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html) - that date/time is simply out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

It only seems to work correctly up to a certain datetime `2262-04-11 23:59`:

[image]

Comment: yes, the comments above led me to [pandas out of bounds](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans) documentation.  This is expected and can be avoided using Periods

Comment: and https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans